# How do I make msbuild find .Net assemblies when using a custom task (UsingTask)>

Tags: .net, ssis, msbuild

I've built a custom msbuild task based on the old CodePlex project:

http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/SSISMSBuild/Project/Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build.csproj

After finally getting this to build in VS 2015 (using the SQL Server 2016 SMSS assemblies) I can use the compiled project DLL to build SSIS projects.

However, I can only get the SSIS project to build (e.g. using a project file such as at https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/) when I copy the assemblies (the custom task DLL and the dependences from SMSS) into a copy of the msbuild bin directory.

Is there any way to direct Msbuild to look in a specific path? I'd rather not add assembles to the GAC if possible.

I've read any web articles and posts but they mostly refer to C# .csproj projects and they refer to setting AssemblySearchPaths and ReferencePath. As this isn't a C# project file I can't use these.

This issue is only occurring on one of my machines (Windows Server 2012). Thing seem to work fine on my Windows 10 machine :(

I can see other people have also seen this issue. E.g.:-
[MsBuild does not look in the good directory for custom task's second-level dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678540/msbuild-does-not-look-in-the-good-directory-for-custom-tasks-second-level-depen)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `<UsingTask>` directive's `AssemblyFile` attribute allows you to specify the full path to the assembly you want to load.

This is usually done relative to the location of the file that wants to use a particular task. e.g. if you build a NuGet package that contains a task, you would usually have a `build/{packageId}.targets` file and for example an `tools/net46/sometasks.dll` that contains the needed tasks. The `.targets` file would then use:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomTask" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\net46\sometasks.dll" />
```

If the task dll also references other assemblies, they need to be located in the same directory as the assembly in order to be discovered.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can get the custom task DLL to build. When I use it in other Msbuild projects is where I have the issue. My msbuild project locates the custom assembly DLL file. It's the dependencies that it can't locate. The dependencies (SMSS DLLs) can't be located by msbuild when I try building my SSIS (.dtproj) projects. I could add these DLLs to the GAC but I'd rather not have to. Only but putting the Msbuild binaries and the SQL Server DLLs and my custom task DLL into a single directory and executing Msbuild from this directory can I get my SSIS projects to build.

Comment: And you put the dependent assemblies into the same folder as the task's dll? MSbuild should be able to resolve the dependencies from the same folder as the task dll (assuming no assembly conflicts with things already loaded)

Comment: Hi Martin - yes, all of the dependencies are in the same folder as the custom task's DLL.

Comment: I've found the issue...a dependency (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration.DLL) of my custom task assembly was being found in the GAC and then the dependencies of *that* we being looked for in the GAC but they aren't there (they're only in my project bin directory). If I remove the assembly from the GAC then things work fine. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I.e. to force msbuild to look in the bin directory for all dependencies?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606867/how-to-prevent-a-net-application-from-loading-referencing-an-assembly-from-the