# How to stop MSBuild from running

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm on a Windows 8.1 machine running VS2013 Community Edition.  When I run my winforms solution, I get 3-4 copies of MSBuild that run as well.  These executables persist even after closing my app.  I've tried everything to get rid of MSBUild, but still it persists:

Based off of previous posts, it looks like the solution is to add an environment variable.  How do I do this?

Also, how to I launch MSBuild with command line arguments? (another common fix)

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12193759/1466046

Answer (score -2):

I've found ReallyStopDebugger  VS2013 extension very useful:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/288d7b16-d78f-4c27-a284-84f2d8b42599

> ***What is it (really)?***
>
> ReallyStopDebugger is a simple Visual Studio extension which allows to
>   stop debugging and kill processes quickly.
>
> ***What can I use it for?***
>
> During development one can stumble upon build errors caused by MSBuild
>   processes or previous debug instances which weren't killed in time,
>   and lock our solutions assemblies/resources, thus stopping the build.
>   This is a quick solution to that problem, altough it can be also
>   considered as a general purpose process killer extension.